# dialup connection in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, connection, lan

I have recently installed `Ubuntu 14.04` on my laptop.

I have a LAN connection which requires dial up to enter user ID and password as provided by ISP.

> Note that I don't have router/modem. In windows LAN works perfectly
>   well.

I have tried the following:

1. Using the `traditional network admin` method shows connection established but there is no Internet connection
2. Using `gnome-ppp` results in: Cannot open modem
3. Using `wvdialconf & wvdial`, which displays:`Cannot open /dev/modem`
4. Using `pppconfig & pon/poff` states : `Connect script failed`.

Comment: In the `Network Admin` menu did you try the following:

- Edit
- Add a new connection
- DSL -> Create 
- Set Username and Password?

And afterwards, use this new network connection?

Comment: @Terrance It's very likely a PPPoE connection (Point-to-Point over Ethernet) (aka DSL)

Comment: @Yaron, yes I've tried it many times.